# Cucumber gives Sqlite3 error

Tags: cucumber, bdd, ruby-on-rails-3

I just started using Cucumber, but I am running into a weird error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: venues: SELECT "venues".* FROM "venues" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
./app/controllers/venues_controller.rb:5:in `index'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:18:in `/^(?:|I )am on (.+)$/'
features/most_popular_bands.feature:8:in `Given I am on the home page'
```

This comes from the `Given` step, where I mention the home page, which has a list of items from the venues tables. I wonder why Cucumber cannot find that table.

Btw, I am not running it with autotest. I am using `bundle exec cucumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with `rake cucumber`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're executing your features on old version of the database. Try `rake db:test:clone`  to copy the scheme of your development database to the test database.